# Angular - The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm testing Angular's `keyvalue` pipe with simple code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let prop of testObj | keyvalue">
      <div>key: {{prop.key}}</div>
      <div>value: {{prop.value}}<div>
    </div> `
})
export class AppComponent {
  testObj = { id: 1, name: "Abdul Rafay" }
}
```

but it's giving me this error:

> Template parse errors: The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found ("]prop of testObj | keyvalue"> key: {{prop.key}} value: {{prop.value}}"):
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@0:17 Evaluating src/main.ts Booting
>   application

am i missing anything? Here's my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-zebsm2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: the keyvalue pipe is available in 6.1 you need to update your dependencies https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-zebsm2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just need to update your dependencies to 6.1 to use `keyvalue` pipe.

Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-pkbcfe?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 6):

The KeyValue Pipe is available in angular 6.1 to Update your dependencies it will work

If you are using angular 6 you can try this

**HTML**

```
  <div *ngFor="let prop of key">
          <div>key: {{prop}}</div>
          <div>value: {{testObj[prop]}}<div>
        </div>
```

**TS**

```
 testObj = { id: 1, name: "Abdul Rafay" }
    get key(){
      return Object.keys(this.testObj);
    }
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-x9hady

Comment: Thanks for giving an alternate solution as well. Upvoted it. :)